# При выводе name из таблицы категории выдается ошибка

Tags: php, yii2

В виджете нужно вывести дерево массива. 
Вот сам виджет:

```
<li>
<a href="">
    <?= $category->['name']?>
    <?php if (isset($category['childs'])):?>
     <span class="badge pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
    <?php endif;?>
</a>
<?php if( isset($category['childs'])):?>

  <ul>
      <?= $this->getMenuHtml($category['childs'])?>
  </ul>

<?php endif;?>
```

Компонент виджета:

```
namespace app\components;
use app\models\Category;
use yii\base\Widget;

class MenuWidget extends Widget{

public $tpl;
public $data;
public $menuHtml;
public $tree;


public function init()
{
parent::init();
if ( $this->tpl === null) {
    $this->tpl = 'menu';
}
$this->tpl .= '.php';
}


public function run(){
    $this->data = Category::find()->indexBy('id')->asArray()->all();
    $this->tree=$this->getTree();
    $this->menuHtml = $this->getMenuHTML($this->tree);
    return $this->menuHtml;
}

public function getTree() {
    $tree = [];
    foreach ($this->data as $id=>&$node) {
     if (!$node['parent_id'])
         $tree[$id] = &$node;
     else
         $this->data[$node['parent_id']]['childs'][$node['id']]=&$node;

    }
return $tree;
    }

    protected function getMenuHTML($tree) {
$str = '';
foreach ($tree as $category) {
    $str .= $this->catToTemplate($category);
}
return $str;
    }

    protected function catToTemplate( $category ) {
   ob_start();
   include __DIR__ . '/menu_tpl/' . $this->tpl;
   return ob_get_clean();
    }

}
```

Ошибка: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `$category->name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в:

```
<?= $category->['name']?>
```

Должно быть или

```
<?= $category['name']?>
```

если это массив или

```
<?= $category->{'name'}?>
<?= $category->name?>
```

если это поле объекта